# Execution of binaries created by specific compiler

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, executable, elf

I want to restrict the execution of the binaries, in Linux, to those only compiled by myself. Lets say my system has gcc with version 4.8.4, I want to allow execution of ELF binaries that are compiled by gcc only installed on my system. Any ELF that is even compiled by same version 4.8.4, should not execute on my system.

`.comment` section contains the version and name of the compiler used to compile ELF. Can we use this information if yes how? 
Any idea and suggestion is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> I want to restrict the execution of the binaries, in Linux, to those only compiled by myself.

Suppose you succeed in this. You *do* realize that your shell, your `gcc`, your `ls` will all immediately stop working (unless you've built them all yourself *prior* to turning on the restriction).

But suppose you have built the entire system, including the compiler, assembler and linker. In this case, you'll want to modify your linker and your kernel such that the linker signs the binaries it links, and your kernel verifies that a valid signature is present, and refuses to run the binary if the signature is invalid. You can read more about code signing [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing).

> `.comment` section contains the version and name of the compiler used to compile ELF.

Normally, it does. However it is trivial to add a `.comment` section with arbitrary contents to an already-linked executable, so you can't base your restriction on the contents of `.comment` (unless you want your restriction to be trivial to bypass).

> can objcopy ease my life without changing linker?

Yes.

I believe you are thinking about your problem in a wrong way (thinking about mechanics before thinking about the substance of your solution).

Assuming you do want to do code signing, you'll need to generate a signature for every binary, and then:

1. Have some means for the kernel to verify that the signature is valid, and
2. Attach the signature to the binary. This could be as easy as having `foo.signature` in the same directory as `foo` for every binary you wish to run. Or you could use `objcpy` to make the signature part of the binary itself (more convenient if you move your binaries around).

Comment: yes I also think same after some reading. can objcopy ease my life without changing linker? Lets say I may add some section with some string and tweak kernel (where and how much?) to match string before execution